# List element {{task.Text}} is not rendering using v-for function in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I've been assigned to create a simple ToDo (task checklist) web application using Vue. The application is able to create a task, toggle (check/uncheck) tasks, delete tasks, and read all tasks created. User tasks are stored in MongoDB.

The issue I'm currently stuck on is that the task details are not being displayed (User not being able to see all of the tasks they created).

[The current display of web application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cxg8u.png)

The following file is a .vue file that lays out the template of how each task should be displayed and functions that enables task to be updated and to be deleted.

`TaskList.vue`

```
<template>
  <div id="task-list">
    <v-list-item-group>
      <v-list-item v-for="task in tasks" :key="task._id">
        <template>
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-btn icon @click="updateTask(task)">
              <v-icon v-if="task.Done=true">check_box</v-icon>
              <v-icon v-else>check_box_outline_blank</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </v-list-item-action>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>
              {{ task.Text }}
            </v-list-item-title>
            <v-list-item-subtitle>
              {{ task.Date }}
            </v-list-item-subtitle>
          </v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-btn icon @click="deleteTask(task)">
              <v-icon color="red">delete</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </v-list-item-action>
        </template>
      </v-list-item>
    </v-list-item-group>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "TaskList",
  props: {
    tasks: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
    updateTask: {
      type: Function,
      default: () => {},
    },
    deleteTask: {
      type: Function,
      default: () => {},
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

I've double checked that user tasks are being retrieved and imported as intended by adding `console.log(data)` in `readTasks()`.

`Home.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <v-card class="mx-auto" max-width="900" v-if="fetched">
      <new-task-form @formSubmit="createTask"></new-task-form>
      <v-divider></v-divider>
      <v-list subheader two-line flat>
        <v-list-subheader>
          {{ user.UserName }}'s Tasks:
        </v-list-subheader>
        <task-list :tasks="tasks" :user="user" :updateTask="updateTask" :deleteTask="deleteTask"></task-list>
      </v-list>
    </v-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { getCurrentDate } from '@/util'
import NewTaskForm from '@/components/NewTaskForm.vue';
import TaskList from '@/components/TaskList.vue';

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    NewTaskForm,
    TaskList
  },
  props: {
    user: Object
  },
  data: () => ({
    fetched: false,
    tasks: [],
    taskForm: {
      Text: '',
      Date: ''
    },
  }),

  
  mounted() {
    this.readTasks();
  },

  methods: {
    // Create a new task
    async createTask(formData) {
      try {
        await fetch(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_ORIGIN}/api/v1/tasks`, {
          method: 'POST',
          credentials: 'include',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(formData),
        });
        this.readTasks();
        console.log("Task created:", formData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  },

    // Read tasks
    async readTasks() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_ORIGIN}/api/v1/tasks`, {
          method: 'GET',
          credentials: 'include',
        });
        if(!response.ok) throw new Error('Failed to fetch tasks');
        const data = await response.json();
        this.tasks = data;
        console.log(data)
        this.fetched = true;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      }
    },

    // Update a task
    async updateTask(task) {
      try {
        await fetch(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_ORIGIN}/api/v1/tasks/${task._id}`, {
          method: 'PUT',
          credentials: 'include',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({Done: "task.Done"}),
        });
        this.readTasks();
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      }
    },

    // Delete a task
    async deleteTask(task) {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_ORIGIN}/api/v1/tasks/${task._id}`, {
          method: 'DELETE',
          credentials: 'include',
        });
        if (response.ok) {
          this.readTasks();
        } else {
          throw new Error('Failed to delete task');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      }
    },
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.form {
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
</style>
```

The following is displayed on console:

```
GET
http://localhost:1337/api/v1/tasks
[HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 356ms]

    
0   Object { _id: "6556cb8a15a22a48d0970a88", UserId: "6549e0c4484119e8a7e0c432", Text: "Create a new task 2 ", … }

_id "6556cb8a15a22a48d0970a88"
UserId  "6549e0c4484119e8a7e0c432"
Text    "Create a new task 2 "
Done    false
Date    "2023-11-17T02:09:58.923Z"
__v 0
```

The only way to be able to display Tasks content is by removing the inner `<template>` in `TaskList.vue`.
[Web app when inner <template> is removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHzXH.png)

However, the assignment specifically requests the following format:
[Requested format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50FJ3.png)

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the `v-slot:default` to your template tag ?

See : https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/list-item-groups/#selection-controls

> Using the default slot, you can access an items internal state and toggle it. Since the active property is a boolean, we use the true-value prop on the checkbox to link its state to the v-list-item.